# How to check validation of a date for the past one year in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to validate "date" to see if the entered date is in the past one year. I am doing this,

```
validates :date, lambda {Date.today - 1.year.ago}
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: well for starters I don't think :date is an activerecord validation helper unless you've defined it yourself somewhere or have a gem that defines it somewhere.

Comment: I suppose the value of the lambda should be boolean, yours just yields a number which is always `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your validation must to return a `Boolean` value. A validation like this one will do the job.

```
  validate :date_must_be_in_past_year
 
  def date_must_be_in_past_year
    if date.present? && date <= 1.year.ago
      errors.add(:date, "date must be within the past year")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go for [Validate Timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) gem. It is a Date and time validation plugin for ActiveModel and Rails.

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0'
```

**Run bundler and generate initializer for the gem:**

```
$ bundle install
$ rails generate validates_timeliness:install
```

Then,in your model use it as below:

```
validates_date :date, :after => lambda { 1.year.ago }
```